# Google Maps Geolocation API demo using PHP

Tags: php, google-maps

I'm trying to use the Google Maps Geolocation API, and for a start I've tried to implement their demo program but something just doesn't work.

Here is my PHP script. I removed the parts about the wifiAccessPoints and the macAddress as they are no use to me:

```
    $demo = array(
        'homeMobileCountryCode'=>310,
        'homeMobileNetworkCode'=>260,
        'radioType'=>'gsm',
        'carrier'=>'T-Mobile',
        'cellTowers'=> array (
            array('cellId'=> 39627456,
            'locationAreaCode'=> 40495,
            'mobileCountryCode'=> 310,
            'mobileNetworkCode'=> 260,
            'age'=> 0,
            'signalStrength'=> -95)
        )
    );


    // Create the context for the request
    $context = array(
        "http" => array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "header" => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n",
        "content" => json_encode($demo)
    )
    );


    print_r($context);

    $xcontext = stream_context_create($context);
    $str = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=xxxMyApiKeyxxx", FALSE, $xcontext);

echo "Response is ";
    if (!$str)
    {echo "empty";}
    else
    {echo "not empty";}
```

Of course I insert my real API Key as I got for the server.
As you can see, I incorporated prints in the code, here is what I see in my REST client application window:

```
    Array
(
    [http] => Array
        (
            [method] => POST
            [header] => Content-Type: application/json

            [content] => {"homeMobileCountryCode":310,"homeMobileNetworkCode":260,"radioType":"gsm","carrier":"T-Mobile","cellTowers":[{"cellId":39627456,"locationAreaCode":40495,"mobileCountryCode":310,"mobileNetworkCode":260,"age":0,"signalStrength":-95}]}
        )

)
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=xxxMyApiKeyxxx): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/communication_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 1275</p>

</div>Response is empty
```

The message seems to be composed correctly but the response is empty.
Even in cases where I use all my quota I'm supposed to receive an error specifying it and not just an empty string.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: I think you should look into CURL rather than file_get_contents.  The api may check your user-agent and you can spoof that with curl.  The forbidden response indicates (I think) that the api is blocking your call because it doesn't want to be scraped.  Is this the javascript api you're using in this manner?

Comment: I have tried to do it with CURL as well. 
I tried using it without encoding the content and got an error that an array was received instead of a string. When I encode the content I don't get any error messages but the response is still empty.

Comment: I think something is blocking your request, google should still return some json with a specific error code

Comment: Do you have any guess what could it be? I've disabled my anti-virus, I didn't set my firewall and I even signed out of Skype but response is still empty.

Comment: anti-virus/firewall/skype comments so I assume this is on localhost?  in my api account settings I had to define where the requests would originate.  I'm also using oauth so maybe you don't have that...but if you do, they might not allow the request from your testing environment if you've setup your api key to only accept requests from your production site

Comment: Solved.

Apparently, creating an API key doesn't mean anything if you don't provide them with a credit card and apparently I missed out on this whole thing...

Sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Apparently, creating an API key doesn't mean anything if you don't provide them with a credit card and apparently I missed out on this whole thing.

I would have expected some error code as promised and not just an empty message along with the HTTP 403...

An important thing to notice here is that using CURL didn't provide the errors at all, though clearly there were some.

Comment: I have provide my credit card data but i am getting not found text when i put `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=API_KEY` at the address bar.